# Using React and Ember in the same Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, reactjs, web-component

I'm thinking about switching from an old Javascript framework to a more modern one. My backend is written in Ruby on Rails (v4.2). What is very appealing to me is the Two-way data binding of Ember. However, the web components and performance of React looks pretty cool as well. So my question is, has anyone tried to use the views of React, combined with the Ember models/controllers? Are there any projects out there that demonstrate that?

An example of this might be something like

```
var component = React.Component {


    getAllPosts(){
       // Get data from the Ember model
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            // React html which uses getAllPosts
        )
    }

}
```

What's your thoughts on this?
Thanks!

Comment: What would be the reason to have both? Ember's components have templating functionality as well. Also, one-way binding is possible with Ember: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/object-model/bindings/

Comment: I would say choose one or the other. As vikram points out, correctly, you can write components with one way data bindings.

Comment: New ember is DDAU-> data-down-actions-up. So there's no 2way databinding unless you hack it with "(mut)" but then it's an old ember in new skin

Comment: Ember's rerender performance/strategy is similar to React. At the moment Ember's initial render speed is being improved as well.